# how I can figure out where the output of my software is printed?

Tags: c++

I just installed Sympol in my Ubuntu. Sympol is an open source software in the mathematics. My problem is that when I run sympol on some input data, I don't know where the output is printed. here in page 6 of this pdf (http://www.math.uni-rostock.de/~rehn/software/sympol-manual-0.1.pdf), it says the output is in .ine or .ext format but I don't know where is these output files!!!!!! please help me if you understand how it works. and it is the website of sympol for installation. http://www.math.uni-rostock.de/~rehn/software/sympol.html
I should add that when it says: Segmentation fault

Comment: So what command are you executing?

Comment: @user463035818 where is documentations file?

Comment: @john sympol --no-automorphisms cut7.ext
where cut7.ext is input file

Comment: @sherek_66 you provided a link to the documentation file

Comment: @user463035818 to be fair, having scanned the documentation they seem to have forgotten to mention where the output is created

Comment: @john to be fair I have to admit that I didnt scan the documentation before writing the comment ;)

Comment: If when you run the program it says `Segmentation fault` then the program has crashed, and that explains why you see no output.

Comment: @john is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @sherek_66 looks like a bug in the software. You should ask the authors.

Comment: @sherek_66 I'm sure there is but ... It's either a bug in the program, an error in your input file, or a mistake you made when you built the program. I'm afraid I have no idea how to fix it though.

Comment: @john even if it was an error with their input, segfaulting seems bad error handling, so I would contend that it's still a bug. Not that it's important, I'm just nitpicking at this point

Comment: @john Even with a `SEGFAULT` you could get some output. If the log files are created after the `SEGFAULT` point, obviously you would not get anything. If it happens after, you should see the log files, although they can be empty if buffers were used and not overflowed by the time the `SEGFAULT` occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu: Assuming your app is actually running properly and you have root permissions, open another terminal, install and run `fatrace`, and watch for file output.  When running, `fatrace` prints all files touched in real-time, so you should be able to see your output file's location if it's getting output.

Reading the docs again and again is almost always the correct answer, but if in this case the documentation is that bad, then watching for the file getting written is another good way to figure it out.

Windows: Sysinternals `procmon` (you can get it from Microsoft) can achieve the same result.